# How can I debug javascript code that is being executed inside microsoft teams tab of android mobile teams application?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, microsoft-teams

I am developing a custom tab for microsoft teams app. For the application inside the custom tab, I need to debug the javascript code flow, like we do in desktop browser. Is there any way we can achieve that.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [DevTools for Microsoft Teams tabs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/developer-tools) help page:

You can also enable the DevTools from the Teams Android client. To enable DevTools, you must:

1. Enable the [developer preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/dev-preview/developer-preview-intro).
2. Connect your device to your desktop computer, and set up your Android device for [remote debugging](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/).
3. In your Chrome browser, open `chrome://inspect/#devices`.
4. Select inspect under the tab you wish to debug, as in the following image:

[image: Select "inspect" under the tab you wish to debug.]